# UIAppearance's "when not contained in"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uiappearance

I am currently spinning a complex web of `UIAppearance` modifiers*, and have come across a problem.

My usage of FlatUIKit's custom `UIBarButton` appearance protocol is causing `MFMailComposerViewController` to complain and stop working.

Therefore, instead of using `UIAppearance`'s `whenContainedIn` method to specify classes that cause modification to occur, is there a way to exclude certain classes, i.e. a "when not contained in"?

**I am talking about the `UIAppearance` protocol that is used to predefine object appearance settings in the app's delegate.*

Answer (score 15):

You can use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` to specify nil modification, which will give the default appearance:

```
[[UIBarButton appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIBarButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposerViewController class], nil] setBarTintColor:nil];
```

As of iOS 9 SDK, there is also

```
[[UIBarButton appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIBarButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MFMailComposerViewController class]] setBarTintColor:nil];
```

Which can be used Swift-2 like so:

```
UIBarButton.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
UIBarButton.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([MFMailComposerViewController.self]).barTintColor = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I used this one which works in iOS 10,

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a custom subclass of all the container view controllers that are being used in the app as the main `UIWindow` subviews (window's root view controller or presented view controllers), such as `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController` or `UISplitViewController`.

Let's say the app is only using `UINavigationController`. Create a subclass:

```
class CustomizedNavigationController: UINavigationController {}
```

Then use the `CustomizedNavigationController` instead of plain `UINavigationController` everywhere in the app.

Also, instead of specifying the appearance for every `UIBarButton`, specify the appearance only when contained in the subclass:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: 
                           [CustomizedNavigationController.self])
```

Because `MFMailComposerViewController` is not using the subclass, it won't get customized.