# iOS 9: Restore default styling to UIAlertController after calling UICollectionViewCell.appearance()

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, swift2, uialertcontroller, uiappearance

Say I want to present a `UIAlertController`:

```swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Whoops.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Go back.", style: .Default) { (_) in }
        alert.addAction(dismiss)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in the app, I've got a `UICollectionView`, which I'm styling using `UIAppearance` in my `AppDelegate` (best to follow [Mattt Thompson](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)'s advice):

```swift
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    UICollectionViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    return true
}
```

This turns the background of the `UIAlertAction` buttons black, which isn't what I intended.

I tried using the new [appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift/26224862#26224862) functionality in iOS 9 to [restore the default styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408582/uiappearances-when-not-contained-in/19408865#19408865)...

```
UICollectionViewCell.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UIAlertController.self]).backgroundColor = nil
```

...but this gives me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on that line.

**How can I use `UICollectionViewCell.appearance()`, without disrupting my `UIAlertController` styling?**